# Match URL pattern in PHP using a regular expression

Tags: php, regex, url

I want to match a URL link in a wall post and replace this link with anchor tag. For this I use the regular expression below.

I would like the match four types of URL:

1. `http://example.com`
2. `https://example.com`
3. `www.example.com`
4. `example.com`

```
preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@',
             '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $subject);
```

This expression matches only first two types of URL.

If I use this expression for matching a URL pattern,
`'@(www?([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@'`, it only matches the third type of URL pattern.

How can I match all four typeS of URL patternS with a single regular expression?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'd use a different regex to be honest. Like this one that [Gruber posted](http://daringfireball.net/2009/11/liberal_regex_for_matching_urls) in 2009:

```
\b(([\w-]+://?|www[.])[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))
```

Or this [updated version that Gruber posted](http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls) in 2010 (thanks, @IMSoP):

```
(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))
```

Comment: Note that there is a newer version of that regex here: http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls

Comment: Implemented in PHP:
[http://stackoverflow.com/a/10002262/1055533](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10002262/1055533)

Answer (score 18):

A complete working example using [*Nev Stokes*' given link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904482/match-url-pattern-in-php-using-a-regular-expression/3904514#3904514):

```
public function clickableUrls($html){
    return $result = preg_replace(
        '%\b(([\w-]+://?|www[.])[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))%s',
        '<a href="$1">$1</a>',
        $html
    );
}
```

Comment: my goodness, finally this one works... i've been trying all kinds of ones that people have posted, either have trouble with the syntax or they partially work (what i needed to fix was that there were periods at the end of the url that were being picked up, like t.co/123213...)

Comment: Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I looked around and didn't see any that were exactly what I needed. I found [this one](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=1121) that was close, so I modified it as follows:

```
^((([hH][tT][tT][pP][sS]?)\:\/\/)?([\w\\-]+(\[\w\.\&%\$\-]+)*)?((([^\s\(\)\<\>\\\"\.\   [\]\,;:]+)(\.[^\s\(\)\<\>\\\"\.\[\]\,;:]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}))|((([01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}([01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])))(\b\:(6553[0-5]|655[0-2]\d|65[0-4]\d{2}|6[0-4]\d{3}|[1-5]\d{4}|[1-9]\d{0,3}|0)\b)?((\/[^\/][\w\.\,\?\'\\\/\+&%\$#\=~_\-]*)*[^\.\,\?\"\'\(\)\[\]!;<>{}\s\x7F-\xFF])?)$
```

Check it out on [debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/?re=%5E(((%5BhH%5D%5BtT%5D%5BtT%5D%5BpP%5D%5BsS%5D%3F)://)%3F(%5B%5Cw-%5D%2B(%5B%5Cw.%26%25$-%5D%2B)*)%3F(((%5B%5E%5Cs()%3C%3E%22.%5B%5D,;:%5D%2B)(.%5B%5E%5Cs()%3C%3E%22.%5B%5D,;:%5D%2B)*(.%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%7B2,4%7D))%7C(((%5B01%5D%3F%5Cd%7B1,2%7D%7C2%5B0-4%5D%5Cd%7C25%5B0-5%5D).)%7B3%7D(%5B01%5D%3F%5Cd%7B1,2%7D%7C2%5B0-4%5D%5Cd%7C25%5B0-5%5D)))(%5Cb:(6553%5B0-5%5D%7C655%5B0-2%5D%5Cd%7C65%5B0-4%5D%5Cd%7B2%7D%7C6%5B0-4%5D%5Cd%7B3%7D%7C%5B1-5%5D%5Cd%7B4%7D%7C%5B1-9%5D%5Cd%7B0,3%7D%7C0)%5Cb)%3F((/%5B%5E/%5D%5B%5Cw.,%3F%27/%2B%26%25$%23%3D%7E_-%5D*)*%5B%5E.,%3F%22%27()%5B%5D!;%3C%3E%7B%7D%5Cs%5Cx7F-%5CxFF%5D)%3F)$).

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
preg_match("/^((https|http|ftp)\:\/\/)?([a-z0-9A-Z]+\.[a-z0-9A-Z]+\.[a-z0-9A-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[a-z0-9A-Z]+\.[a-z0-9A-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[a-z0-9A-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$/i", $url)
```

Answer (score 1):

I just checked this post (after two years). It might be you got the answer, but for those who are beginners, you can use a regular expression to strip every type of URL or query string

```
(https|http|ftp)\:\/\/|([a-z0-9A-Z]+\.[a-z0-9A-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})|([a-z0-9A-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})|\?([a-zA-Z0-9]+[\&\=\#a-z]+)
```

It will strip every type of URLs. Take a look at the following list. I used a different type of domains for those who want to ask "will it strip .us, .in, .pk, etc.? type of domains or not.

1. ftp://www.web.com
2. web.net
3. [www.website.info](http://www.website.info)
4. website.us
5. web.ws?query=true
6. [www.web.biz?query=true](http://www.web.biz?query=true)
7. ftp://web.in?query=true
8. media.google.com
9. ns.google.pk
10. ww1.smart.au
11. www3.smart.br
12. w1.smart.so
13. ?ques==two&t=p
14. http://website.info?ques==two&t=p
15. https://www.weborwebsite.com

Working Example (tested in PHP5+, Apache2+):

```
$str = "ftp://www.web.com, web.net, www.website.info, website.us, web.ws?query=true, www.web.biz?query=true, ftp://web.in?query=true, media.google.com hello world, working more with ns ns.google.pk or ww1.smart.au and www3.smart.br w1.smart.so ?ques==two&t=p http://website.info?ques==two&t=p https://www.weborwebsite.com and ftp://www.hotmail.br";
echo preg_replace("/(https|http|ftp)\:\/\/|([a-z0-9A-Z]+\.[a-z0-9A-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})|([a-z0-9A-Z]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})|\?([a-zA-Z0-9]+[\&\=\#a-z]+)/i", "", $str);
```

it will return

```
, , , , , , , hello world, working more with ns or and and
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make that one work, you need to make the "https?//" part optional. Since you seem to have a fairly good grasp of regexps I won't show you. It is an exercise for the reader :)

But I generally agree [with Nev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904482/match-url-pattern-in-php-using-a-regular-expression/3904514#3904514). It's overly complicated for what it does.

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern:

```
$regex = "(https?\:\/\/|ftp\:\/\/|www\.|[a-z0-9-]+)+([a-z0-9-]+)\.+([a-z]{2,4})((\/|\.)+([a-z0-9-_.\/]*)$|$)";
```

Answer (score 0):

This works great for me - including mailto check:

```
function LinkIt($text)
{
    $t = preg_replace("/(\b(?:(?:http(s)?|ftp):\/\/|(www\.)))([-a-züöäß0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/im", '<a target="_blank" href="http$2://$3$4" class="external-link" title="External Link">$1$4</a>', $text);
    return preg_replace("/([\w+\.\-]+@[\w+\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})/im", strtolower('<a href="mailto:$1" class="mail" title="E-Mail">$1</a>'), $t);
}
```