# Linkify Regex Function PHP Daring Fireball Method

Tags: php, regex, linkify

So, I know there are a ton of related questions on SO, but none of them are quite what I'm looking for. I'm trying to implement a PHP function that will convert text URLs from a user-generated post into links. I'm using the 'improved' Regex from Daring Fireball towards the bottom of the page: http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls
The function does not return anything, and I'm not sure why.

```
<?php
if ( false === function_exists('linkify') ):   
  function linkify($str) {
$pattern = '(?xi)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))';     
return preg_replace($pattern, "<a href=\"\\0\" rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\">\\0</a>", $str);      
}
endif;
?>
```

Can someone please help me get this to work?
Thanks!

Comment: This exact question came up before, but it's indeed difficult to google. But enabled `error_reporting` would have told you *instantly*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
$pattern = '(?xi)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`\!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))';     
return preg_replace("!$pattern!i", "<a href=\"\\0\" rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\">\\0</a>", $str);
```

PHP's `preg` function do need [delimiters](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). The `i` at the end makes it case-insensitive

### Update

If you use `#` as the delimiter, you wan't need to escape the `!` in the pattern as such use the original pattern string (the pattern does not have a `#`): `"#$pattern#i"`

### Update 2

To ensure that the links are correct, do this:

```
$pattern = '(?xi)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))';
return preg_replace_callback("#$pattern#i", function($matches) {
    $input = $matches[0];
    $url = preg_match('!^https?://!i', $input) ? $input : "http://$input";
    return '<a href="' . $url . '" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">' . "$input</a>";
}, $str);
```

This will now append `http://` to the urls so that browser doesn't think it is a relative link.

Comment: Thanks. Will try to avoid answers without explanation in the future.

Comment: Thank you @d_inevitable ! It seems to be recognizing the links correctly now. Works perfectly for links starting with 'http:'. However for something like 'www.google.com' the new tab address shows 'http//www.mysite.com/directory/www.google.com' I'm a bit of a novice-- thanks so much!

Comment: @Jeff this is because the new link must include the `http://` prefix in the `href` attribute. I don't think you can do this with single function call. Try `preg_replace_callback` and an if-statement that will prepend `http://` when necessary.

Comment: Thanks again. I'll look into that and give it a shot.

Comment: @Jeff ive udpated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Wow, that's great! Seems to work for `www.google.com` and `https://www.google.com` but `http://stackoverflow.com` ends up as `http://http//stackoverflow.com/`

Comment: `$url = preg_match('!^http?s://!i', $input) ? $input : "http://$input";` should be changed to `$url = preg_match('!^https?://!i', $input) ? $input : "http://$input";` The question mark just had to be moved one spot over.

Comment: this is working great. Wondering if you have any advice to make it xss safe using PHP. Thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319284/is-this-linkify-method-at-risk-for-xss-attacks

Answer (score 3):

I was looking to just get the urls from a string using the same regex from the answer above by [d_inevitable](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1238764/d-inevitable) and wasn't looking to turn them into links or care about the rest of the string, I only wanted the urls with in the string so this is what I did. Hope it helps.

```
/**
 * Returns the urls in an array from a string.
 * This dos NOT return the string, only the urls with-in.
 */
function get_urls($str){

    $regex = '(?xi)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))';
    preg_match_all("#$regex#i", $str, $matches);
    $urls = $matches[0];
    return $urls;

}
```