# Regular expression pattern to match url with or without http(s) and without tags

Tags: php, regex, expression

I'm not very good at regular expressions at all.

What I am trying to do? I want to match all url's in a special string.

Basically, I want to match all urls to enclose them with an `<a>`- Tag, except the existing `<a>`- Tags.

**For example, the following string should be matched:**

> Hallo! I am a text click here, that has a lot
>   of urls www.aon.at?this=true and www.aon.at. all should be matched
>   correctly http://www.aon.at and also working for aon.at/this?true

**What should be matched:**

> Hallo! I am a text < a href='www.aon.at' >click here < /a >, that has a lot
>   of urls **www.aon.at?this=true** and **www.aon.at**. all should be matched
>   correctly **http://www.aon.at** and also working for **aon.at/this?true**

I have tried the regex from [Linkify Regex Function PHP Daring Fireball Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10002227/linkify-regex-function-php-daring-fireball-method/10002262#10002262)

```
(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:\/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}\/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))
```

on the page https://regex101.com/ but it is not working the way I want it to do. As you can see, the regex is matching the `<a>`- Tag, and I don't know how to remove it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, found the solution already.

With that solution, everything works fine

```
$pattern = '(?xi)\b((?:https?://|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`\!()\[\]{};:\'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))';     
return preg_replace("!$pattern!i", "<a href=\"\\0\" rel=\"nofollow\" target=\"_blank\">\\0</a>", $str);
```