# replace many urls into links

Tags: php, url, hyperlink, str-replace, preg-match-all

Here's my code:

```
$post = $_POST['test'];
$pattren='/((([http]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\/+=&#?;%@,.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*)?))/';
preg_match_all( $pattren, $post, $matches);

foreach($matches[0] as $match) {
    $images[]= "<a href=\"$match\" target=\"_blank\" >$match</a> ";
}

for ($i = 0, $c = count($images); $i < $c; $i++) {
    $html_links = str_replace($pattren,$images[$i], $post);
}

echo $html_links;
```

I'm trying to get all urls from `$post` and convert them to links, but something is wrong.

Comment: Shouldn't `$pattren` be `$pattern`? (oops, just noticed that IMSoP mentioned this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [preg_replace()](http://php.net/preg_replace)

```
$post = $_POST['test'];
$pattren='%\b(([\w-]+://?|www[.])[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))%s';
$html_links = preg_replace($pattren, '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $post);
echo $html_links;
```

Updated with a good pattern from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11641499/204701).

Comment: While this eliminates most of the problem code I mentioned, I'm still not convinced of the usefulness of that regular expression.

Comment: I didn't check the pattern, but modified. Check answer

Comment: Well, it took me a while to figure out why, but yeah, that works. I see there's a newer (and better explained) version here: http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls

Answer (score 2):

There are many things wrong with this code, including:

Not sure where you've got your regular expression (`$pattren`) from, but it looks like complete gibberish to me - `[http]{3,9}:` means "any of the characters 'h', 't', or 'p', repeated between 3 and 9 times, followed by a colon" - so it would match "thppppppt:", which doesn't look much like the beginning of a URL to me.

`str_replace` has nothing to do with regular expressions, so `str_replace($pattren, ...` is looking for the text of that regular expression in the input.

In actual fact, I'm not sure what replacement you are expecting to happen in that loop, since you've already copied `$match` into the correct parts of the string.

You are over-writing the variable `$html_links` every time around your second loop. There is also no need for 2 loops, unless there is code not shown - you could simply build the string in the `foreach` loop and do away with the `$images` array altogether.

And, incidentally, you have spelled "pattern" wrong, and used an inconsistent convention for your curly-braces - some prefer the `{` on its own line, some on the line with the `for`/`foreach`, but you've managed one of each. [Neither of these will affect the code, though]