# cut http://somelink/withparams and put it into <a href=""> tags

Tags: php, javascript

I've been thinking about http:// determination in the string and putting it into

For ex. I have a string:  `Performed at Dublin Pub "You Give Love a Bad Name/Hit The Road Jack" yesterday http://t.co/FgXluI4H`
In this string I have `http://t.co/FgXluI4H`  that is not clickable. When echo-ing this string I'd like to determine this `http://t.co/FgXluI4H` and put it into `<a href="http://t.co/FgXluI4H" target="_blank">t.co/FgXluI4H</a>`

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks!

Thanks mates for your posts! the links in the comments are really helpful!

Comment: Your `href` attribute is actually wrong it should be `<a href="http://t.co/FgXluI4H" target="_blank">t.co/FgXluI4H</a>`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked into PHP preg_replace() at all?

Comment: @SmokeyPHP - yes I have but got confused after loosing info after .co/ I searched for solutions, but couldn't get one, maybe someone here has good enough experience to resolve this problem.

Comment: Duplicate from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904482/match-url-pattern-in-php-using-regular-expression

Comment: This question has been asked numerous times on SO. It should be stated that detecting URLs is a tedious job because there are so many valid ways to write an URL. For every solution, someone manages to find a valid URL that breaks it. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/5341344/911182

Answer (score 2):

you can use something like this:

`function makeLink($text){
    $reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\://[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/\S*)?/";
    if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $text, $url)) $text = preg_replace($reg_exUrl, '<a href="'.$url[0].'" target="_blank">'.$url[0].'</a>', $text);
    return $text;

}`

Comment: From looking at it, this doesn't seem to properly support multiple URLs. Granted, the OP might not need support for multiple URLs, but it might be worth mentioning.

Comment: @Twista has the right concept. I'd use a different regexp like    http(s)?\://[a-zA-Z0-9-]+([.a-zA-Z0-9-])*[\S]*

Comment: But this is realy a duplicate from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904482/match-url-pattern-in-php-using-regular-expression

Comment: Ok, thanks for posting, I'll try this option and see how it works. @Nir Levy thanks for pointing to another post, I'll check that out too. The thing is that I'd like to determine only http:// type of URL, and not www at least for now. The mission of replacement is to substitute links with formated <a href="" way on the file, and if there are multiple URL, i want all of them to be replaced.

Comment: for multiple urls you can modify function -


function makeLink($text){
  $reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
  preg_match_all($reg_exUrl, $text, $url);
  foreach ($url[0] as $key => $value) {
   $text = strtr($text, array($value => '<a href="'.$value.'" target="_blank">'.$value.'</a>'));
  }
  return $text;
}

[link](http://pastebin.com/bfU03Ywf)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't put it under rigorous testing and is not very 'fussy' about the URL structure, but should work nonetheless (for numerous URLs, and only starting with http(s)).

```
$urlRegex = '((https?://))([a-z0-9\.\-]{1,63})\.(([a-z]{2,3})\.?)+/?([^ ]+)';
$parsed = preg_replace('#'.$urlRegex.'#','<a href="$0">$0</a>',$text);
```