# Using php to get parent element of link with URL

Tags: php, parent, href

I'm trying to implement a "find and replace" system for broken links. The problem is, for some links there are no replacements. So, I need to comment out certain li elements. You can see my code below to do this. (I'm starting with an HTML form).

```
<?php

$brokenlink = $_POST['brokenlink'];
$newlink = $_POST['newlink'];

$brokenlink = '"' . $brokenlink . '"';
$newlink = '"' . $newlink . '"';

$di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('hugedirectory');
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($di) as $filename => $file) {
  //  echo $filename . ' - ' . $file->getSize() . ' bytes <br/>';

    $filetoedit = file_get_contents($file);
    if(strpos($filetoedit, $brokenlink)) {

    echo $brokenlink . "found in " . $filename . "<br/>";
    $filetoedit = str_replace($brokenlink, $newlink, $filetoedit);
    file_put_contents($filename, $filetoedit);

    }

}

?>
```

What I want to accomplish is this: If I have a URL, I want to be able to find its li parent. For instance, I want PHP to be able to comment out the code below if the user inputs http://www.espn.com in an HTML form, I want php to find this element on my server:

```
 <li><a href="http://www.espn.com" target="_blank" data-new="20120627">Sports</a></li>
```

And replace it with this:

```
 <!-- <li><a href="http://www.espn.com" target="_blank" data-new="20120627">Sports</a></li> -->
```

Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: Feel like I could help you here... But I cant seem to make sense of what your trying to do. Could you edit in an example of what your desired result would look like?

Comment: thanks for the reply, I edited to clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try using this to parse the DOM.

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

You can set a class to all the ones you want comment out.  Then use this tool to find those classes and comment them all out at once.

Comment: thanks that did it for me: $matches = $html->find("a[href=$brokenlink]");

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a regexp to find and replace  links, it would also take care of the perhaps expensive looping over links. 
Here's a regex for matching urls
http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls

then preg_replace the broken with the new, or the broken with the commented out version of the  broken link

Alternatively you can just run grep on the directory via shell_exec, that way you don't have to open / read and parse files yourself.

Also take a look at this [match url pattern in php using regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904482/match-url-pattern-in-php-using-regular-expression)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you construct [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) with the file content and use [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) to search for the broken link node.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($filetoedit);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$nodes = $xpath->query('//li/a[@href="' . $brokenlink . '"]');
for ($i = 0; $i < $nodes->length; $i++) {
    $node = $nodes->item($i);
    // Do whatever you want here
}
```